# Spring IllegalAccessError: Tried to access ValueFormatter from class ValueFormatterWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having a bizarre issue with Spring. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong and I suspect that it is an issue with Spring itself, but I can never be so sure. I can't find any reference to this error anywhere else on the internet, so I've come to StackOverflow for help.

I'm using Spring Boot and I am parsing a thymeleaf template. When I'm parsing the template, I've found that as soon as my template attempts to parse a th:field value, I get an exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatter from class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatterWrapper`

I'm not sure what's happening and I've found that if I remove the th:field from my template it processes the template just fine. There are no references to my code in the stack trace, it's all Spring, Thymeleaf, and Tomcat stuff. Which leads me to believe that this is an actual Spring bug.

Some of the stack trace is below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatter from class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatterWrapper
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatterWrapper.getDisplayString(ValueFormatterWrapper.java:40)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor.java:110)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:179)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:352)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    ... 49 more
```

The specific line in my template in question is:

```
<input type="text" th:field="${configForm.configs[__${configIter.index}__].siteId}" th:text="${progressItemAttribute.attribute.name != null} ? ${progressItemAttribute.attribute.name} : 'null value!'"/>
```

Comment: This makes me suspect you have a version mismatch somewhere. Post your POM or Gradle build.

Comment: This project is massive, the effective pom is 1 million lines long. Do you know of any simpler way to search the dependencies for the spring versions?

Comment: I don't belive it is a version mismatch - I just blew away my .m2 folder and rebuilt the project, and there are no instances of the same library being present in .m2 with multiple versions.

Comment: I didn't ask for *effective* POM, but the fact that you have one that massive does indicate that there's something wrong in the specs. But again, I didn't say "multiple versions", I said "mismatch", such as pulling in a 4.3 and a 5.0 of something.